# Hybrid Derivatives Modelling

Tags: derivatives, asset-pricing, big-list

Could you please recommend any good books and papers that thoroughly describe the pricing and modelling of Hybrid derivatives? I.e. this question is a "big list" question, the more the better.

Will put a bounty on to reward the best answers as the the list grows.

To be clear, by Hybrids, I mean any pay-offs that depend on multiple underlyings, could be for example:

- rates with FX
- rates with credit, structured notes
- convertibles,

etc. I am particularly interested in hybrids that include rates, but I will appreciate any resources, including those covering equity hybrids that have some sort of correlations embedded into the pricing.

Thank you so much,

Comment: This is quite a good book, there is a chapter on long dated and hybrids but not sure it fully covers what you are looking for: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781119170433

Comment: [Oliver Brockhaus. Equity Derivatives and Hybrids. Markets, Models and Methods (2016)](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1137349484) has a good introduction to eqities-IR and equities-credit hybrids.

Comment: [Uwe Wystup. FX options and structured products.  (2017)](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0470011459) has good discussions of FX hybrids.

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen! Do you / does anyone have any experience with [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Exotic-Options-Hybrids-Wiley-Finance/dp/0470688033/ref=sr_1_7?crid=2J4NRF1WOS2CH&keywords=Hybrid+derivatives&qid=1642685234&sprefix=hybrid+derivatives%2Caps%2C84&sr=8-7&asin=0470688033&revisionId=&format=4&depth=1) by Bouzoubaa & Osseiran?

Comment: I do not own the Bouzoubaa book, but have heard that it is a good place to start. Browsing through its ToC it appears to give a good overview of hybrids.

Comment: ah yes, I downloaded this one too :) Good explanation of various products, a little on on hybrids in chapters 19 and 20. I'm sorry I really can't think off hand of any book that discusses credit-rates and credit-commodies relations, the ones most dear to my heart.

Comment: @DimitriVulis: yes, Credit-Rates is what I am after the most. Would you have any resources for Credit-Rates that you like to use? Whether some SSRN papers you'd recommend, or perhaps some notes of your own you'd be happy to share? :)

Comment: I'm going to look through my old notes and see what I can e-mail to you (probably this weekend). (I actually once gave a talk at a seminar about credit-commodity hybrid poduct.)

Comment: We should also mention for completeness Satyajit Das. Structured Products Volume 1 Exotic Options; Interest Rates and Currency https://www.amazon.com/dp/0470821663 and Volume 2 Equity; Commodity; Credit and New Markets https://www.amazon.com/dp/0470821671